# Повторное использование кода AngularJS-приложения с передачей аргументов

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Имеется код приложения на AngularJS:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MainController', [ '$scope', function($scope){
       $scope. ...
    }]);
```

В шаблоне предполагается использовать в разных местах. При этом передавая различные аргументы в модуль приложения или в контроллер:

```
<div id="app-1" ng-controller="MainController">
    ...
</div>
...
<div id="app-2" ng-controller="MainController">
   ... 
</div>
```

Как можно реализовать передачу аргументов?

P.S. При инициализации приложения используется `angular.bootstrap(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то Вам нужно использовать в зависимости от места использования данного контроллера различные значения для инициализации.

Как насчет использовать **ng-init** директиву?

```
<div ng-controller="MainController as mctrl" ng-init="mctrl.initialize('app-1','param1','param2')">
</div>
```

Сам контроллер:

```
angular.module('app', [])
        .controller('MainController', [ '$scope', function($scope){
           $scope.initialize = function (id, param1, param2){
               $scope.id = id;
               $scope.param1 = param1;
               $scope.param2 = param2;
        }
    }]);
```